# Duda con liberar memoria utilizando for anidado

Tags: c, bucle-for, bucles

¡Hola! tengo una duda con lo siguiente:

Tengo un árbol binario donde tengo diferentes tipos de datos que corresponden a diferentes estructuras enlazadas entre ellas. Bueno, la cuestión es que necesito implementar una función que se llame copiar. Esta libera memoria de los datos del Alumno 1 para introducirle los datos del alumno 2.

El código que uso es el siguiente.

```
void copiar(void *datos1, void *datos2) {

    Alumnos *A1 = (Alumnos*)datos1;
    Alumnos *A2 = (Alumnos*)datos2;

    int i, j;

    //Lo primero que hacemos es liberar

    for (i = 0; i < A1->numAsig; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < A1->asignaturas[i].numParciales; j++) {
            free(A1->asignaturas[i].parciales);
        }
        free(A1->asignaturas);
    }

    //creamos memoria


    A1->asignaturas = (Alumnos*)malloc(A2->numAsig * sizeof(Alumnos));  //memoria para el array de asignaturas
    for (i = 0; i < A2->numAsig; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < A2->asignaturas[i].numParciales; j++) {

            A1->asignaturas[i].parciales = (Parcial*)malloc(A2->asignaturas[i].numParciales * sizeof(Parcial)); //memoria para el array de parciales
        }
    }

    //Datos estáticos:

    A1->numAsig = A2->numAsig;
    strcpy(A1->nombre, A2->nombre);
    strcpy(A1->expediente, A2->expediente);
    /////

    /*Copiamos datos*/


    for (i = 0; i < A2->numAsig; i++) {
        A1->asignaturas[i].codAsignatura = A2->asignaturas[i].codAsignatura;
        A1->asignaturas[i].notaAsignatura = A2->asignaturas[i].notaAsignatura;
        strcpy(A1->asignaturas[i].numParciales, A2->asignaturas[i].numParciales);
        strcpy(A1->asignaturas[i].nomAsignatura, A2->asignaturas[i].nomAsignatura);
        for (j = 0; j < A2->asignaturas[i].numParciales;j++) {

            A1->asignaturas[i].parciales[j].notaParcial = A2->asignaturas[i].parciales[j].notaParcial;
            strcpy(A1->asignaturas[i].parciales[j].fecha, A2->asignaturas[i].parciales[j].fecha);

        }
    }


}
```

Mi duda es con la parte del código que libera memoria del alumno 1, tanto del array asignatura como de parciales.

```
for (i = 0; i < A1->numAsig; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < A1->asignaturas[i].numParciales; j++) {
            free(A1->asignaturas[i].parciales);
        }
        free(A1->asignaturas);
    }
```

¿Es correcto este código para liberar memoria? mi duda viene porque me dice un compañero de clase que este bucle no sirve ya que libera asignaturas más de una vez lo que llevaría a un error.

Muchas gracias por las respuestas que me puedan brindar.

(edito)

Las estructuras son las siguientes:

```
typedef struct {
    char fecha[11];
    float notaParcial;
}Parcial;

typedef struct {
    char nomAsignatura[60];
    int codAsignatura;
    float notaAsignatura;
    int numParciales;
    Parcial *parciales;
}Asig;
```

Donde parciales corresponde con un array a los diferentes parciales hechos por las distintas asignaturas.

```
typedef struct {

    char nombre[100];
    char expediente[20];
    int numAsig;
    Asig *asignaturas;
}Alumnos;
```

Donde asignaturas corresponde al array de las diferentes asignaturas que se ha matriculado el alumno.

Comment: El `free()` no parece usar para nada el índice `j`, así que ¿para qué es el bucle interno? Se limita a liberar N veces el mismo objeto que es `A1->asignaturas[i].parciales` (siendo N el valor de `numparciales` para la asignatura `i`-´ésima). Supongo que deberías liberar `A1->asignaturas[i].parciales[j]`, pero no tengo muy clara tu estructura de datos. También tienes mal la parte tras el comentario `//creamos memoria`, por la misma razón. El bucle con índice `j` no usa la `j` dentro.

Comment: Hola @abulafia, he añadido las estructuras. Para saber si haciéndolo así como dices:  A1->asignaturas[i].parciales[j] sería lo correcto.

Haciendo solo A1->asignaturas[i].parciales no estaría liberando directamente todos los parciales de dicha asignatura del alumno 1?

Comment: No, estarías liberando el array que contiene los punteros a los parciales. Pero antes de liberar ese array necesitas liberar lo apuntado por cada puntero. En realidad tienes que hacer ambas cosas, pero en el orden correcto, de "dentro a fuera". Primero liberas cada parcial (iterando en `j` en bucle), y cuando ya estén todos liberados, liberas también `A1->asignaturas[i].parciales`